# Executing cy.request in a for-loop

Tags: javascript, cypress

I'm trying to write code that will let the user specify the number of items to create via Cypress (this flexibility is needed for some of our tests).

```
function createSomeItems(itemCount, headers)
{
    item: { id: 0, field1: 123, field2: "test text!"};
    let chain;
    for (let i = 0; i < itemCount; i++)
    {
        chain = cy.request({method: 'POST', url: '/create-item', body: item, headers: headers});
        item.id += 1;
    }
    return chain;
}
```

The problem is that the application hits an error because of duplicate ID for the items. From what I can see, the call to `cy.request` does not actually execute when I think it does.

I'm still very new to Cypress (and this is the first time I've used JavaScript in about 15 years), so I'm not sure how to resolve this.

I know I could have *n* calls to `cy.request().then()...` chained together explicitly, though this will make the tests large and hard to read (especially for test cases that require larger values of *n*) and I'm trying to keep the code neat and compact.

Comment: Did you read e.g. https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/request#Call-cy-request-over-and-over-again? You should also check out https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases to start understanding Cypress's async model.

Comment: @jonrsharpe No, actually, I had not yet seen those. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who is curious, I came up with a solution that returns the chain of commands (unlike the [example from Cypress](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/request#Call-cy-request-over-and-over-again)):

```
function createSomeItems(itemCount, headers)
{
    let item = { id: 0, field1: 123, field2: "test text!"};

    function recursiveRequester(itemNumber, chain)
    {
        item.my_id = itemNumber;

        return chain.then(() => {
            return cy.request({method: 'POST', url: '/create-item', body: item, headers: headers});
                .then(() => {
                    if (itemNumber === itemCount) {
                        return chain;
                    }
                    else {
                        return recursiveRequester(itemNumber + 1, chain);
                    }
                })
        })
    }

    
    return recursiveRequester(1, functionThatDoesOtherSetupwork());

}
```